# Bootstrap 3 typeahead not working with bootstrap tags

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following the tutorial from following link, [bootstrap3-tutorial](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/bootstrap3/). Now in that link there is an example as below,

HTML code,

```
<input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" />
```

jQuery code,

```
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
  }
});
```

When I type 'S', it is expected that I get the suggestion 'Sydney', but the problem is I'm not getting any suggestions.
Below are the files that I'm importing,

```
<link href="bootstrap3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="typeaheadjs.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="typeahead.js"></script>
```

So why I'm not getting any suggestions? You can also suggest me some other way through which I can generate suggestions for creating bootstrap tags.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove `data-role="tagsinput"`, since you are calling the plugin directly.

Also, add an Id to the `input`.

So your  should become:

```
<input type="text" id="id1" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" />
```

And use should change your jquery to:

```
$(function () {
    $('#id1').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
            source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
        }
    });
});
```

This should work.

Comment: i want to pass data something like that : "source:[[1,"Alabama"],[2,"Alaska"],[3,"Arizona"],[4,"Arkansas"]]". Can it be possible or not ?